# clothes sanitizer vs clothes detergent

Tags: cleaning, washing-machine

Recently I came across a product called a clothes sanitizer.

Is this just marketing or is there a difference between clothes detergents vs clothes sanitizers?

Are clothes sanitizers more effective at killing viruses (think Covid) or is detergent just as good?

Comment: This isn't a home improvement question, and appliance usage is off-topic. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @isherwood, "appliance" referring to?

Comment: I assume a clothes washing machine.

Comment: @isherwood, Water and pail aren't appliances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laundry sanitizer is a different chemical than detergents and is targeted at killing microbes. Apparently pine oil is an example for a natural laundry sanitizer. Other types include phenolic, chlorine based or quaternary if you want to do some more research on the chemicals. And yes they are more effective at killing microbes than detergent. Many microbes can survive regular detergent and it is the high water temperature that can kill them though.

Laundry sanitizer is either an additive to be added to regular detergent or it is a complete product which includes the detergent. Be careful and read the instructions on your brand closely because some sanitizers cannot be mixed with regular detergent or there will be a bad chemical reaction.

Comment: By "better" do you mean that I can do away with detergents completely and simply use sanitizers from now on ?

Comment: I don't think I would recommend that. It just means if you need to sterilize clothing they are better for that.

Comment: @Pacerier, don't forget that if the sanitizer says `kills 99.9% of bacteria`, that it means that is leaves several billion bacteria still alive

Comment: @jsotola, Is it better to use detergent or sanitizer for clothes if say just in case your housemate has Covid?